# Can copyToRealmOrUpdate be used to make object managed by realm or only copyToRealm?

Tags: java, android, database, realm

I was wondering about the simple question if the realm method `copyToRealmOrUpdate` converts a POJO to a managed object or if it does just the realm method `copyToRealm`?

In the [official documentation](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#faq-pojo-vs-realmobject) it only mentions the `copyToRealm` method that "converts between the two states".

Comment: the `OrUpdate()` version does the exact same thing, except it overwrites existing object in the db if primary key is the same. `copyToRealm()` throws exception "duplicate primary key" then

Comment: Great, thanks @EpicPandaForce